# Twitter Bootstrap inputmask filter for time

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been using twitter bootstrap for a project, and I need a field to capture a time in 24hr format. The masks provided by default are very basic and don't allow for a regex (as far as I know), but digging in the bootstrap-inputmask.js code, I found this:

```
$.fn.inputmask.defaults = {
mask: "",
placeholder: "_",
definitions: {
  '9': "[0-9]",
  'a': "[A-Za-z]",
  '?': "[A-Za-z0-9]",
  '*': "."   
   }
}
```

So I added 2 new lines:

```
'h': "[01][0-9]|2[0-3]",
's': "[0-5][0-9]"
```

This is how I define the HTML input:

```
<input type="text" id="EventHour" data-mask="h:s"/>
```

When I render the page, the text field displays indeed the **:** placeholder, but it doesn't allow any character at all (no number, no alphabetic). Can anyone out there hint me at what I am doing wrong? Do I need to add more code anywhere on that script?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?